# Using Right function in If statement causes syntax error

Tags: vb.net, reportbuilder3.0

I have a multiple-value-single-string as a parameter field in a report in Report Builder 3.0 (e.g. 20124, 20125). Now I want to split up this string, and show "Summer 2012" instead of "20124" and "Fall 2012" instead of "20125. I am using Visual Basic. Here is my two functions I have made in Report Builder 3.0 custom code. The error is in the second function in the "If Right(yearterm)..." line. It gives me a syntax error. If I write "String.Right" it gives me the error: "'Right' is not a member of 'String'". If i take out the whole "If statement" the report will run but "20124,20125" gives me this: ", 2012, 2012".

How can I make this work?

```
Public Function SplitParameterValues(ByVal parameter As Parameter) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim a(0 To 10) As String
    a = Split(parameter.Value, ",")

    For i As Integer = 0 to a.length - 1
        result = result +", "  + YearTermTranslation(a(i))
    Next

    Return result
End Function

Public Function YearTermTranslation(ByVal yearterm As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim term As String
    Dim year = Left(yearterm, 4)

    If Right(yearterm, 1) = 5
    Then term = "Fall"
    Else If Right(yearterm, 1) = 4
    Then term = "Summer"
    Else If Right(yearterm, 1) = 3
    Then term = "Spring"
    Else term = "Winter"
    End If

    result = term + " " + year

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: @user1258439: Are you doing this in VBA? I have a strong feeling that you are doing this in vb.net? The reason I ask is because you are using "Dim year = Left(yearterm, 4)
"  and "Return result" which is not a VBA/VB6 Syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're putting your `Then`s on separate lines, as well as a syntax error in your `Else`; it has nothing to do with `Right` - unless that's a copy-paste error.

```
Public Function YearTermTranslation(ByVal yearterm As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim term As String
    Dim year = Left(yearterm, 4)

    If Right(yearterm, 1) = 5 Then
        term = "Fall"
    ElseIf Right(yearterm, 1) = 4 Then
        term = "Summer"
    ElseIf Right(yearterm, 1) = 3 Then
        term = "Spring"
    Else
        term = "Winter"
    End If

    result = term + " " + year

    Return result
End Function
```

Oh, and if this is actually VB.NET... please learn VB.NET.

```
Public Function SplitParameterValues(ByVal parameter As Parameter) As String
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    Dim a() As String = parameter.Value.Split(","c)

    For i As Integer = 0 To a.length - 1
        result &= ", " & YearTermTranslation(a(i))
    Next

    Return result
End Function

Public Function YearTermTranslation(ByVal yearterm As String) As String
    Dim term As String
    Dim year As String = yearterm.Substring(0, 4)

    Select Case yearterm(yearterm.Length - 1)
        Case "5"c
            term = "Fall"
        Case "4"c
            term = "Summer"
        Case "3"c
            term = "Spring"
        Case Else
            term = "Winter"
    End Select

    Return term & " " & year
End Function
```

Comment: Please check this answer as the right one so this question doesn't result in the unanswered section anymore.